# Are all processes started by a Slurm job killed on cancelling the job?

Tags: linux, slurm

If a Slurm job starts processes (could even be daemons), would all of them be automatically killed if I stop the job with scancel?

Answer (score 2):

Yes if Slurm is configured with `cgroup` support. See details in the [documentation](https://slurm.schedmd.com/cgroups.html)

A `cgroup` is created upon job start and all processes belong to that `cgroup`. Once the job is terminated, the `cgroup` is removed and all processes then killed by the kernel.